# Storing and reading configurations in Liferay

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I have problems using the PortletPreferences in my portlet. The `doView(...)` method shows the normal **view.jsp** or a custom jsp called **controlpanel.jsp** depending on the page id (**controlpanel.jsp** shows up in Liferays ControlPanel, **view.jsp** anywhere else).

I added a form in the controlpanel-page, where user can type in database-properties. When the user submits the form, the data will be processed and saved if not empty. Here's my action-method:

```
@ProcessAction(name="saveControlPanelSettings")
public void saveControlPanelSettings(ActionRequest actionRequest,
        ActionResponse actionResponse) throws ReadOnlyException, ValidatorException, IOException {
    String host, port, user, pass;

    host = ParamUtil.get(actionRequest, "host", StringPool.BLANK);
    port = ParamUtil.get(actionRequest, "port", StringPool.BLANK);
    user = ParamUtil.get(actionRequest, "user", StringPool.BLANK);
    pass = ParamUtil.get(actionRequest, "password", StringPool.BLANK);

    if(host.equals(StringPool.BLANK) || port.equals(StringPool.BLANK) || 
            user.equals(StringPool.BLANK)) {
        SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, "blank-fields");
    } else {
        PortletPreferences prefs = actionRequest.getPreferences();
        prefs.setValue("host", host);
        prefs.setValue("port", port);
        prefs.setValue("user", user);
        prefs.setValue("password", pass);
        prefs.store();
        System.out.println(String.format("Settings saved... [host: %s]",
                prefs.getValue("host", "NULL")));
    }
}
```

The last row, which pulls the host preference, shows me the correct string in the console. The controlpanel-page is then also filled with correct data. However, if I try to show the settings in my **view.jsp** nothing is returned! :(

Here's my `doView(...)`:

```
@Override
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest,
        RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {

    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay =
            (ThemeDisplay)renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    String themeId = themeDisplay.getThemeId();

    String jsp;

    if(themeId.equalsIgnoreCase("controlpanel")) {
        jsp = "/html/ekmsserviceoverview/controlpanel.jsp";
    } else {
        jsp = "/html/ekmsserviceoverview/view.jsp";
        PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();
        renderRequest.setAttribute("test", prefs.getValue("host", "NULL"));
    }

    this.viewTemplate = jsp;

    super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
}
```

In the **controlpanel.jsp** I was able to get the preferences via `portletPreferences.getValue("host", "")`. In **view.jsp** neither that method nor getting the preference in the jsp by setting it with `renderRequest.setAttribute(...)` worked.

What am I doing wrong? Is this the wrong way for saving those data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a Configuration Action to save preferences, or use Liferay's DefaultConfigurationAction.

However, changing the way you obtain preferences in your saveControlPanelSettings action may work:

```
PortletPreferences preferences;
String portletResource = ParamUtil.getString(request, "portletResource");
if (Validator.isNotNull(portletResource)) {
    preferences = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortletSetup(request, portletResource);
}
```

Comment: I get a NullPointerException... :(

Comment: Weirdo. I suggest you implement ConfigurationAction for portlet configurations, or use liferay's DefaultConfigurationAction. See here: http://www.liferay.com/web/jit066124/blog/-/blogs/unique-way-to-save-portlet-preferences-in-liferay-6-1